# Why does Ruby's hash method vary across runs?

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.9

```
# pry / irb example #1
"abc".hash
=> -1883761119486508070
"abc".hash
=> -1883761119486508070

# pry / irb example #2
"abc".hash
=> -4309321811150053495
"abc".hash
=> -4309321811150053495
```

The `hash` value is constant for a particular invocation, but varies across invocations. Why? Is this by design? Is this considered a "good thing"?

I'm running `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to page 23 of http://patshaughnessy.net/Ruby-Under-a-Microscope-Rough-Draft-May.pdf

> Here’s how Ruby’s hash function actually works ... [snip] ... For string and arrays it works differently. In this case, Ruby actually iterates through all 
>   of the characters
>   in the string or elements in the array and calculates a cumulative hash value; this guarantees that the
>   hash value will always be the same for any instance of a string or array, and will always change if any of
>   the values in that string or array change.

And:

> Also, Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 2.0 initialize MurmurHash using a random seed value which is
>   reinitialized each time you restart Ruby. This means that if you stop and restart Ruby you’ll
>   get different hash values for the same input data. It also means if you try this yourself
>   you’ll get different values than I did above. However, the hash values will always be the
>   same within the same Ruby process.

Comment: Random seeds when generating a hash are better for security. I can't remember where I saw this, but I'm almost sure that's why this happens.

Comment: Here is the link to official vulnerability bulletin 

 http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/12/28/denial-of-service-attack-was-found-for-rubys-hash-algorithm-cve-2011-4815/